# Capture dynamic list to an array using Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, selectlist

I've re-written this question so that it makes more sense.

Is there a way to enable Ruby to listen for a newly created (dynamic) select-list on a webpage and save that list into an array?

This would be the scenario:

1. User Selects a Branch number, 02
2. User selects a person type, missionary
3. A new dynamic select list of missionary names is generated

Ruby would need to capture the dynamically created list of names and save them into an array.  This is the code thus far:

```
missionaries = Array.new

browser.select_list(:id,'branch_select').select_value('02')
browser.select_list(:id,'user_type_select').select_value('1') # 1 = Missionary
browser.select_list(:index,2).click # <-This is the dynamically created list
missionaries = browser.select_list(:index,2) # <-This is just a guess, doesn't work
puts "Missionary List: " + missionaires.to_s # <-Prints to verify list saved
```

What this actually prints to screen is this:

```
 Missionary List: #<Watir::Select:0x147e54e>
```

Comment: The dynamic list is generated somewhere in the page when that select list option is chosen?

Or the options within the select list IS the dynamic list?

I've offered an answer for any select_list object below.

Comment: What do you want to do with the list of options?  print them out? Look for a particular one and select it?  get the values and text and print both?  there's a lot of possibilities once you have the list of the options.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, this is what I am attempting to do with the returned list (if I can get it).  I'd like to be able to enumerate how many options are available in the dynamic list, so if the list returned a list of 7 missionary names, I'd need to just know that there were 7 missionaries. (Updated my question code as well from comment below)

Comment: The code above would print to screen, "Missionary List: #<Watir::OptionCollection:0xd5163a>"

Comment: Just out of curiosity (still new here), how come there have been so many comments, answers, and discussion about this question, but no upvotes for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.  The list was being dynamically populated by a JSON call.  What I've had to do is first figure out what happens when the second list item is selected (in this case, missionaries).  As soon as that was selected, a GET request was sent, then a JSON string was received.

The string had to be captured by Ruby using the open-uri gem/library.  Then parsed using the json gem.  After that I used regex to count the amount of times that a new id was found.  Here's the new code:

```
browser.select_list(:id,'branch_select').select_value('01')
browser.select_list(:id,'user_type_select').select_value('1') 
browser.select_list(:index,2).click
json = open("http://10.5.26.9:8080/MissionaryLetters/getUsers?branchID=01&userTypeID=1").read
json = JSON.parse(json)
puts json
missionaries = json.to_s.scan(/id\d/).length
puts missionaries
```

This would print the amount of missionaries found in the Branch, in this case 16.

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you, but I will say that if it is displayed on the page, the combination of Ruby and Watir/Watir-Webdriver will be able to display it.  At least, I haven't run into a situation where it couldn't (and that's kind of the point of the library).  So, you may be able to get rid of the overheard of the extra library once you are able to figure it out.

Comment: You've had great comments throughout, I've upvoted your answers, thanks!

Comment: @adamreed So you're saying that I ought to be able to capture that dynamically populated third select list just using watir, without having to catch the JSON response?  Any other ideas that might do that?  The other suggestions didn't seem to grab it from the page.

Comment: absolutely - Ruby doesn't care how content is generated if it's available in the DOM (unless it's Flash...).  One of the caveats to this are AJAX items that may take time to populate.  Like anonygoose suggests, you may try a sleep just to see if that's the case (as he mentions, this is not a final solution, just a good test).  I've shared all the ideas I can think of without seeing the real page.  If I'm not able to experiment with the objects, it's difficult to tell which direction to go... If I think of anything else I will add it!

Comment: If you run your original script (such that the web browser is still open) and then *manually* check the dynamically populated dropdown, is it populated as expected? I am starting to think the problem is that the triggers to update the dynamic dropdown are not firing. I have had that problem and it took various poking to get it to work.

Comment: If that's the case it could be a .fire_event("onchange") needed which has often been the case with fields that trigger updates for me in the past.

Comment: That could be it, it does not populate the list until it is clicked.  As soon as it is clicked, it sends a GET request, then receives an answer via JSON.

Comment: I'm sorry, the third list isn't populated, and thus the GET request isn't sent, until the user clicks an option in the second select-list.

Comment: give browser.select_list(:id,'user_type_select').fire_event("onchange") a try if you haven't already, again you'll probably need a sleep between this and whatever you're using to count the number of options in the select list, as it wont be instant

Answer (score 3):

There are many different ruby-tastic ways to collect information to an array (like collect, etc), here's one:

```
@myArray = Array.new

@browser.select_list(:how, what).options.each do |option|
  @myArray << option
end
```

Since "options" gives you all of the options in Array format, you can also (and probably should) just do:

```
@myArray = @browser.select_list.options
```

Update based on your comment - that code generated the list you were looking for, but you did not specify what you're looking to do with it.  The output you see is the Ruby Object format of the list.  In the same way we iterated over the items above, you can iterate through your array options:

```
@num = 0
@myArray.each do |option|
   @num += 1
   puts "#{@num}. option"
end
```

- Output would look like:

  1. Baseball
  2. Basketball
  3. Underwater basketweaving

You can write them to a file, the console, save them, etc.  Those are straightforward Ruby things to do. Hope that helps!

Update #2 based on your comment:  I believe that you need to simplify how you're thinking about the application.  We're no longer talking about missionaries or basketballs or even a webpage.  Since we have identified the object you needed to access (the select_list), and pulled its data into an Array, we can now perform actions on it.

We have an Array.  We know that this Array contains all of the individual options from a select_list.  We can use any Ruby Array methods then to do *something* to this data.  If we want the total number of options:

```
@myArray.length
(basically, @browser.select_list.options.length)
```

Likewise, you can delete_at with this Array, you can re-order its contents, or you can display each item as I did in Update #1.

Comment: That was close, this is what I added and what I got back:

browser.select_list(:id,'branch_select').select_value('01')
browser.select_list(:id,'user_type_select').select_value('1') 
browser.select_list(:index,2).click
missionaries = browser.select_list(:index,2).options
puts "Missionary List: " + missionaires.to_s
Returns:

    Missionary List: #<Watir::OptionCollection:0xf757b9>

Comment: It would be easier if you could edit your question and add that information, that will allow it to be properly formatted instead of wrapped around in a comment to a proposed answer where it is hard to read and may be missed by someone reading the original question.

Comment: Updated this post to reflect your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still unable to actually grab the dynamic list of missionaries returned from the web page and save it into an array.  The reason for doing this being that I need to know how many elements are in the array, or in other words, how many missionaries are available in the Branch.

Comment: @urbanaut - you're looking for a total number of missionaries?  Your original post could be GREATLY clarified by including your final goal, as well as the HTML of the page.  I am updating this post again.

Comment: I appreciate the additions to your answer, but I am still unable to capture or save the dynamically created list into an array. `@myArray = @browser.select_list.options` still doesn't actually capture anything.  Is there any way to tell Ruby to listen for a dynamically populated list and then capture that list's contents?

Comment: Ruby/Watir doesn't care how the list was generated.  If you can see it on the page and it's available to interact with, it's just a select_list.  Other options are that it's not the right select_list, or it's not a select_list at all and rather a div, etc.  Since we can't see the page and there is no HTML to look at in your post, it's difficult to tell.

Comment: The third select list is not in the HTML source, as it's dynamic.  After further investigation, it appears that the dynamic content (the select-list) was being delivered via JSON, so I had to set up a JSON listener. I'll post more in a moment...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
missionaries = Array.new

browser.select_list(:id,'branch_select').select_value('02')
browser.select_list(:id,'user_type_select').select_value('1') # 1 = Missionary
browser.select_list(:index,2).click # <-Assuming this is the dynamic list
missionaries = browser.select_list(:index,2).options.collect{ |x| x.text } #Create an array containing the text of each option in the dynamic list
puts "Missionary List: " + missionaires.to_s # <-Prints to verify list saved
puts missionaires.length # <-Prints number of options in dynamic list
```

Note that this is basically Adam's suggestion with some refinements based on the following assumptions:

1. You are not interested in the options collection. Instead, you want an array containing the text of the dynamic dropdown.
2. Based on your output to `missionaires.to_s`, you are using Watir-Webdriver, rather than classic Watir. From what I tested, OptionCollection.to_s gives different results between Watir and Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, that was close to what I needed too, upvoted.

Comment: I think the only thing wrong with this is potentially a missing wait.  If it's dynamically generated just a little bit slower than you're requesting it, it'll just tell you what it sees at the time.  Have you tried sleeping just after your click on the select list?  If that works you could try something like browser.wait_until{browser.select_list(:index,2).options.count > 1} before setting your missionaries variable.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on my comment, I've located an example of the problem I think you're experiencing when getting the number of options that are returned to you

b is my browser instance because I'm lazy.

```
b.goto("http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/select.html")
b.select_list(:id => "ctlJob").select("Developer")
puts b.select_list(:id => "ctlPerson").options.count
=> 3
```

So in my above example it's outputting 3 (I'm expecting 2) because at the time the dynamic list has not had time to update.  It can often take a second or more for the contents to refresh.  If I tweak the example to wait, it should (and does) return the correct number for me.

```
b.goto("http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/select.html")
b.select_list(:id => "ctlJob").select("Developer")
sleep 5
puts b.select_list(:id => "ctlPerson").options.count
=> 2
```

This time you get the correct number of options because it's had time to update the options in the list (during the sleep) so that when you ask Watir to give you the count it returns the correct number and not an "outdated" one.

But lets face it, sleeps are the devil.  In my experience it's wise to not use sleeps beyond a "is it a timing issue I'm having?" debug situation.

So how can we improve the behaviour of the script above?  Give it a condition to wait for before taking the count of options.

```
b.goto("http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/select.html")
original_option = b.select_list(:id => "ctlPerson").options[1].text
b.select_list(:id => "ctlJob").select("Developer")
# Pay attention to the line below
b.wait_until{b.select_list(:id => "ctlPerson").options[1].text != original_option}
puts b.select_list(:id => "ctlPerson").options.count
```

So in the above example it waits until the text of the first option has changed before it takes a count of the options in the list.  I chose options[1] because there's often a "Select..." default option, so if you use 0 it'll wait until it times out in a lot of cases.

So yeah, I think a lot of the other answers on this page were returning you a 0 for the count because the select list was genuinely empty when Watir was looking at it, and only **after** was the page dynamically updating the list.

Edit:

So for an example of how you might go about it based on your supplied example

```
browser.select_list(:id,'branch_select').select_value('02')
browser.select_list(:id,'user_type_select').select_value('1') # 1 = Missionary
# Im not sure you need to click here at all
browser.select_list(:index,2).click # <-This is the dynamically created list
# As the other answers were all returning zero, lets wait until the option count is higher
browser.wait_until{browser.select_list(:index,2).options.count > 0}
missionaries = browser.select_list(:index,2).options.count
# Potentially minus 1 if there's a "Select..." option
assert(missionaries == number_im_expecting)
```

Comment: So I've taken a look at your example page and it's very similar to what I am testing, but not exactly.  Let me explain further, when I view your resharper page source code I can see all the options in your lists.  In the page I am testing, when I view source, I cannot see any options for the dynamic select list, because those options are received using JSON with a GET call sending the first to select list options, then returning the new select list options in a JSON string.  So that's what I am trying to get ruby to see, and what I was able to accomplish in my answer above.

Comment: Net tab in Chrome shows me it's receiving the contents of the select_list as JSON exactly as you're describing.  The content for the select list updates.  Are you using Internet Explorer?  Make sure to click the refresh icon in the dev tools (f12) if that's what you're using to assert that there're no options in the select list.  Also try running your code in IRB if you havent already.  Let your script run through, then do a count.  Then manually alter the select list to trigger the update of the dynamic select list.  Then run the same count code again.  If the 2nd time you get a count...

Comment: then we're dealing with something that isn't being triggered properly and possibly just need to find the correct series of events to fire off.